# class components function not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i have a problem
  this is a class components:

```
import React from 'react';  
import ListToDo from './ListToDo';


export default class TestClass extends React.Component{
    state ={
        tasks:[]
    }


    async componentDidMount(){
        const response = await fetch('https://nztodo.herokuapp.com/api/task/?format=json');
        const tasks = await response.json
        this.setState({
            tasks
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <ul className="list-group">
             {
                this.state.tasks.map(function(singleTask){
                    return <ListToDo task={singleTask} key={singleTask.id} />
                })
            }
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

the error is:
    **TypeError: this.state.tasks.map is not a function**}
why?
I need install some?

Comment: What are you doing here? ```this.setState({
            tasks
        });``` This does not set anything. Therefore, the error you are getting is not about the component, but about the tasks object being with a wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json` is a function. You are assigning it to the `tasks` state. So when you try to use `Array.prototype.map()`, `tasks` is not an array.

Call it instead of assigning it to tasks:

```js
    async componentDidMount(){
        const response = await fetch('https://nztodo.herokuapp.com/api/task/?format=json');
        const tasks = await response.json() // Call json function here
        this.setState({
            tasks
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

response.json is a function, hence you cannot map over a function.
just change this line to

```js
const tasks = await response.json();
```